# Fixing suitable for corrugated conduit inside a chased masonary wall and suitable clips?

Tags: electrical

I was looking at some [Corrugated Conduit Black 20mm X 10m](https://www.screwfix.ie/p/tower-corrugated-conduit-black-20mm-x-10m/50443) and I was wondering what fixings would be suitable for terminating inside a wall connecting to the backbox (the gland). I can find glands for normal round conduit but I'm having trouble getting the ones suitable for this stuff.

I'm from Ireland so it's the same as the UK regs.

Also what clips would you advise for inside the chased masonry wall which will be plastered over? And I suppose some SS masonry nails would do the job?

[Would these do?](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01LZX3E5K/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza)
[image]

[Here's the corrugated conduit.](https://www.screwfix.ie/p/tower-corrugated-conduit-black-20mm-x-10m/50443)
[image]

Comment: In the US a remodel inside a wall doesn’t require support , we call the corrugated tube smurf tube here and it can be handy for 3way switches in enclosed walls. I usually use single hole clamps with flex nonmetallic tubing (when the walls are open).

Comment: Thanks. So the smurf tube is okay for placing inside the chase and covering over with plaster? I suppose the conduit being corrugated means that the plaster can grip much better. I have 30mm deep chase so there should be ample room. Would these single hole clamps do the job? https://i.imgur.com/bZPaT62.png

Comment: Note, we call it smurf tube because it is usually blue. Not always but many times it is, I don’t see clamps in your add but see my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2017 NEC article 362.10.1.B allows flexible non metallic conduit (smurf tube) concealed in walls floors and ceilings.
362.30.A securely fastened every 3 feet. 
Zip tie anchors are even allowed code added a statement that the zip tie had to be listed for securing and supporting (my state deletes this because this is what a zip tie is for). I usually purchase a bag of plastic clamps that are held in with a nail or screws if 1 hole at the start and end of a run I will use 2 one on each side so when fishing the wire through it it won’t pull lose from the clamps and on the inside radius of any unsupported turn when the wires pull tight if the clamp is on the outside it can pull out on occasion if the wall is closed you may not even notice it.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to go with the corrugated tube as normal, then some R clamps (or P clamps). Then pre-drill a hole and then use some concrete screws 6 X 40mm to secure the tube in place with the P clamps.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Yes, I watched this video by Thomas Nagy and got that suggestion for the concrete screws in the comments.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLMrQx5jp54&t=2s That channel is great btw.